# npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"

Tags: node.js, truffle

I am trying to create a Dapp using truffle but when I reach the stage of using the command npm run dev it gives me an error saying MISSING SCRIP. my code is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "eth-vreg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Blockchain vreg Powered By Ethereum",
  "main": "truffle-config.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    
    "dev": "lite-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && sexit 1"

  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the command to run when executing `npm run`. in this case `node`

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node lite-server",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && sexit 1"
}
```

You can read more about the `scripts` property [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts).

Comment: I think running the command on a wrong dir

Comment: Also make sure that your `lite-server` file is on the same dir as your `package.json`